# Why this code is showing me undefined and type error?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This code is showing error and giving me undefined can anyone pls give me logic for this:

```js
const data = ['1','2','3','4','6'];

const consoleItem = (item, index ,arr) =>{
    console.log(item);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(arr);
} 
data.forEach(consoleItem())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax was incorrect.  The way you have it setup, it only calls `consoleItem` once and it calls it with no parameters, and the return value is used as a parameter to `foreach`.

The way I am using it below, `consoleItem` is acting as a callback to the `forEach` method and I am passing it the three parameters implicitly given by each iteration of the `forEach` method.

Try it like this.

```js
const data = ['1','2','3','4','6'];

const consoleItem = (item, index ,arr) =>{
    console.log(item);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(arr);
} 
data.forEach(consoleItem)
//data.forEach((x,y,z) => {consoleItem(x,y,z)})  Same as above
```

Comment: So you mean i was invoking func inside the forEach method which was wrong we should use it as callback here.

Comment: @Anil  Indeed.  You have it correct good sir

Comment: @Anil  The part below that is commented out is essentially a more verbose way of doing the exact same thing.  I think it does a better job of explaining what it is doing

Answer (score -1):

The function *forEach* require a function definition, but you are invoking the function in forEach it self you can use something like this

```js
const data = ['1','2','3','4','6'];

const consoleItem = (item, index ,arr) =>{
    console.log(item);
    console.log(index);
    console.log(arr);
} 
data.forEach(consoleItem)
```

Comment: he is invoking the function in forEach, but we have to pass the definition not function result, that's why, I corrected the code and post it. I don't know the reason of rating it as negative. You have changed your answer to look like mine by editing that,